# Firebase SDK no support for OSX in 2.4.2

Tags: macos, firebase

I'm working on an OSX project that uses Firebase's SDK. I'm using OSX 10.10.5 with XCode 7.0.1 (7A1001).

I'm modified my Podfile to get the latest release of Firebase (2.4.2)

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.4.1'
```

Only to receive this error message when executing `pod update`

```
[!] The platform of the target `Pods` (OS X 10.10) is not compatible with `Firebase (2.4.2)`, which does not support `osx`.
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Edit--**

This is different from the question posed here: [OSX application fails to compile after adding the Firebase Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749176/osx-application-fails-to-compile-after-adding-the-firebase-library) While both problems can be fixed with the same method, these are 2 distinct issues. Each merits its own independent question as others might be falling into either problem in the future given the lack of documentation from the Firebase (until the time of this edit).

Comment: Looks like osx was dropped from their podspec after [2.3.3](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/Firebase/2.3.3/Firebase.podspec.json). Perhaps a mistake on their part?

Comment: @AnidMonsur I raised an issue where the library failed to compile for versions > 2.3.3 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749176/osx-application-fails-to-compile-after-adding-the-firebase-library The answer I believe is in the second comment which was received minutes ago. I'm gonna test it and if it pulls through will close this question

Comment: Neat. If it works, you should post it as an answer here too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For OSX going forward with 2.4.2 the `FirebaseOSX` pod can be used.

Updates to the Podfile can be like the below:

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!
pod 'FirebaseOSX', '>= 2.4.2'
```

Everything works perfectly afterwards.

Comment: that doesn't work any more. I get this error: FirebaseOSX (>= 2.4.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.